# Is spell attack bonus added to hail of thorns?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, ranger, bonus-type

When using *hail of thorns* is the spell attack bonus added to the roll?

Comment: Can you clarify what game/edition you're asking about?  And perhaps provide more detail about what exactly you mean by "spell attack bonus," and which roll it might be added to?

Comment: I'm with @A_S00: without knowing which roll you're talking about--and for all I know you're talking about the originating attack roll, damage roll, the targets' saves, or something else--I can't tell whether the answers that come in are good ones.

Comment: Using 5E, asking about adding the spell attack modifier to the D10 damage roll from hail of thorns spell, not the weapons damage roll.

Answer (score 4):

**No**.  On the first successful hit (*using a normal weapon attack*), Hail of Thorns forces the targets within 5' to make a Dexterity save against the spellcaster's spell DC or else take full damage (half damage on a miss).  The spell DC for the character's spells is calculating similarly, but separately form the character's spell attack bonus.

> **Spell casting Ability** (*Ranger*)
>
> Wisdom is your spellcasting ability for your ranger
>   spells, since your magic draws on your attunement to
>   nature. You use your Wisdom whenever a spell refers
>   to your spellcasting ability. In addition, you use your
>   Wisdom modifier when setting the saving throw DC for
>   a ranger spell you cast and when making an attack roll
>   with one.
>
> **Spell save DC** = 8 + your proficiency bonus +
>   your Wisdom modifier
>
> **Spell attack modifier** = your proficiency bonus +
>   your Wisdom modifier